# How to enforce zod schema types with remapped fields using toZod

Tags: typescript, zod

I'm trying to map a schema key to another name for my db

```
interface Country {
        isoCode: string,
        nameEn: string,
        nameDe: string,
        phone: string,
        bla: string
}

const CountryJson = {
        isoCode: 'DE',
        nameEn: 'Germany',
        nameDe: 'Deutschland',
        phone: '+49',
        blubb: 'test123'
}

const testZodObj: toZod<Country> = z.object({
        isoCode: z.string(),
        nameEn: z.string(),
        nameDe: z.string(),
        phone: z.string(),
        blubb: z.string(),
}).transform((item)=>{
        const {blubb: bla, ...rest} = item
        return {
                ...rest,
                bla
        }
})

type countryArray = z.infer<typeof testZodObj>

function print(): countryArray{
        return testZodObj.parse(CountryJson)
}

const out = print()
console.log(out)
```

but transform returns a zodType, due to toZod testZodObj now expects a ZodEffects.
Any Ideas How I could achieve the key name to match the interface?

`blubb` is the way I get it from the api and `bla` is the way I would like to store it.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying the problem statement somewhat, assume we have the following remote and local types:

```js
interface ILocal {
  a: number;
}

interface IRemote {
  b: number;
}
```

After parsing, you expect the number field `b` that you pull down from the API to be under a new key: `a`. This can be achieved in a straightforward way with an explicit type definition as follows:

```js
import { z } from 'zod';
const schema: z.ZodType<ILocal, z.ZodTypeDef, IRemote> = z.object({
  b: z.number(),
}).transform(({ b }) => ({ a: b }));

console.log(schema.parse({ b: 11 }).a); // => 11
```

The important part of this that I think you may've been missing is the explicit input type being different from the output type. `z.ZodType` takes 3 generic parameters, but typically it is enough to just specify the output type as there is usually no key remapping.

In this case, you want to remap a key, so to get the correct types, you need to pass in the third parameter explicitly.

The return type from `.transform(...)` is still going to be a `ZodEffect`, but it will be assignable to this explicit `ZodType`.

You already have your `Country` interface, so you don't strictly need to use `z.infer`, but if you wanted to get rid of the `ILocal` interface in my example and instead use `z.infer`:

```js
const schema = z.object({
  b: z.number(),
}).transform(({ b }) => ({ a: b }));
type Local = z.infer<typeof schema>;
```

`Local` will be inferred as the same type as `ILocal` (+/- differences between `type` and `interface`)

---

**Getting into opinion territory so please consider this as separate from my answer, but I think it's relevant**

I read a bit more trying to figure out any missing context, and I stumbled across the `toZod` library which is what I'm guessing is causing issues. To be totally honest, I'm not sure I understand the point in using that library when you can achieve the same thing with the base `zod` library as described above. `z.ZodType<ILocal, z.ZodTypeDef, IRemote>` as an explicit type definition will force the `zod` schema on the RHS to match. If you define a schema that outputs something different, then you will get a type error without the need to use `toZod`.

Just to show your exact scenario:

```js
// Just defining this to avoid duplication
interface IBaseCountry {
  isoCode: string;
  nameEn: string;
  nameDe: string;
  phone: string;
}
interface Country extends IBaseCountry {
  bla: string;
}
interface RemoteCountry extends IBaseCountry {
  blubb: string;
}

const testZodObj: z.ZodType<Country, z.ZodTypeDef, RemoteCountry> = z.object({
  // Your code
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I was trying to avoid the possibility to add properties into the z.object which are not available in the interface.
right now I could place foo as a property even though it's not in the interface ```const testZodObj: z.ZodType<Country, z.ZodTypeDef, RemoteCountry> = z.object({
  foo: z.string()
});```